# Getting old records from Sails Models

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, models, record

Im actually trying to build up a complete **chat** with **Sails.js websockets** but im facing some troubles.

I succeed to send and get new messages when a new client connect to the chat but i would new client to **get the older messages** (like the 20 last messages sent in the chat).

Message.js (Model)

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name    : { type: 'string' },
    message : { type: 'string' }
  }
};
```

MessageController.js (Controller)

```
module.exports = {
    new: function(req, res) {
        var data = {
            name: req.param('name'),
            message: req.param('message'),
        };      

        Message.create(data).exec(function created(err, message){
            Message.publishCreate({id: message.id, name: message.name, message: message.message});
        });

    },

    subscribe: function(req, res) {     
        Message.watch(req);
    }
};
```

I had an idea about using the "find" function on my Model but not really conclusive.

I hope im not missing something big about Sails possibilities !

Need your help :) Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Message.find({sort: 'createdAt ASC'}).exec(function(err, results) {
  //results is an array of messages
});
```

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language

Comment: So, in the subscribe function of the Controller you broadcast to the new client the previous messages ? No other and maybe clean way to do it ?

And, doing this, how you receive it on the client ? Im using AngularJS Controller and emit data seems not to triger the onMessage event :/

Comment: You don't need to do this in the subscribe. Sails has blueprints so you can simply make a GET request to /message?sort=created ASC. OR, you can overwrite sails' blueprints and make your own "find" function in your controller. Anyway, you would be better off with Express than with Sails. It will even be more educational.

Answer (score 0):

I added this code to my **subscribe function** but i don't receive anything on my client side listening **on('message')**

```
/* Get the last 5 messages */
Message.find({sort: 'createdAt DESC'}).limit(5).exec(function(err, messages) {
    for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        sails.sockets.broadcast(req.socket, 'message', messages[i]);
    }
});
```